# rsync: [sender] out of memory: my_alloc caller (file=lib/pool_alloc.c, line=143)

Tags: rsync

I am trying to rsync a dir that includes a subdir with a ridiculous amount of files. So it was not a complete surprise when I got:

```
[sender] out of memory: my_alloc caller (file=lib/pool_alloc.c, line=143)
```

The server side runs out of memory.

Is there a way I can tell `rsync` to keep fewer file names in memory - maybe by using a tempfile for the file names?

```
root@remote-end:~# rsync --version
rsync  version 3.2.3  protocol version 31
```

Comment: Can you share the actual command you are running? And what version of rsync is running on the other side?

Comment: Some flags for `rsync` use a chunk of memory. Seeing the actual command would help - to the point that the question is probably unanswerable without it

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a crappy workaround:

```
# Copy the dir structure without files
ssh remote 'cd srcdir; find . -type d' | parallel mkdir -p
find . -type d |
  # Sort so the deep dirs come first
  perl -e 'print sort { $b=~s:/:/:g <=> $a=~s:/:/:g; } <>;' |
  parallel rsync -a remote:srcdir/{} {}
```

It will still fail in the end, but hopefully only after all subdirs have been synced.